# Rubymotion TableView Not not rendering all sections

Tags: uitableview, rubymotion

I'm attempting to add a tableview to an existing UIViewController in my app. The implementation can be found here: https://gist.github.com/naderhen/8161526

It seems to be working okay for the most part, but it doesn't look like the delegate is calling the numberofSectionsinTableView method at all. Throwing some logging text in there returns nothing.

When I run the app in the simulator I get [image: missing domain!]

There don't seem to be any errors in the console...I'm sure I am missing something very simple as I have done this a number of times in the past but can't get it working now.

Any help would be very much appreciated..thank you!

Answer (score 1):

adding

```
  def numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView)
    self.domains.length
  end
```

seemed to fix it

Comment: Yeah, `tableView:numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is a redundant method name.